# Using QEMU to run and configure Raspbian from its microSD card

Tags: raspbian, emulation, qemu

So, my general goal is to emulate a Raspberry Pi via an ARM emulator in Windows 10. I, essentially, want to initialize the card and configure it so I can either ssh (I'm not entirely sure how to do that, but that's why I bought the thing) or, more likely, VNC into the device over an ethernet cable and operate it with my laptop's keyboard and mouse.

To this effect, I downloaded and installed a QEMU binary from here, http://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/, specifically qemu-w64-setup-20150811.exe (version 2.4.0). I understand I need to use the command line here, and I've figured that I need to qemu-system-armw.exe (I could be wrong) to emulate the ARM architecture of a RPi, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to string commands together to get a virtualization to boot off of the SD card. I've read as much of the documentation as I could but it still seems unclear.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I *think* there's no difference between emulating a PI from an image file and an SD card on Windows. On Linux there is none as Qemu treats image files or disks equally. I expect to be no difference on Windows either.

Comment: Saying "I've read as much of the documentation as I could but it still seems unclear," is unlikely to lead to anything very productive, beyond, (as per Nasha's first link) links to more documentation that you may or may not have read.  It would be better if you explain an actual attempt, and at what point it fails and/or becomes "unclear" to you.